# How to pass string to REST API using libcurl in cpp

Tags: python, c++, c, http, libcurl

I want to send string to my rest API call in c++. So, I am using libcurl library.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost:5000/sample");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"hi\" : \"there\"}");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

O/P  from flask API is,

> ImmutableMultiDict([('{"hi" : "there"}', '')])

the above code is working:

I am getting the sent result in my python Flask application.

but,

```
string body = "{\"hi\" : \"there\"}";
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost:5000/sample");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

O/P from flask API is:

> ImmutableMultiDict([('��-ؿ\x7f', '')])

this code is not working. the only difference is i am assigning the string to a variable and passing that to curl.

I am wondering why it's working?
how to pass variable to curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ...);` expects a `char*` as it's parameter, which you give in the first exmaple but not in the second. Try `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body.c_str());` instead.

In C++ string literals have type `char*` (not actually true, but close enough for now) which is a legacy from C. The `string` type is different. Use `string::c_str()` if you have a C++ string but need to call a function which requires a legacy C string.

Comment: Be very careful if you're using `.c.str()` here. _"The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS option."_ ([ref](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)).

Answer (score 1):

`curl_easy_setopt` is a function with a C-like interface that uses "variadic arguments", since the types of those arguments depends on the option being set.

That means it is not type-safe. Your compiler cannot detect when you've used the wrong type, as you have here. [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` wants a `char*`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) (a pointer to some `char`s), not a `std::string` (a complex C++ class type).

So, you should not be passing `std::string`, and it's not clear why you think it should, as the documentation clearly states that a `char*` is expected.

However, you should have at least received a warning from your compiler about passing non-PODs through variadic templates. Turn on your warnings, and read documentation.